# How to insert new line in a data column of sql ? I want to get my data with new lines inserted when i retrieve my data from sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am creating a website, entered my data (my blog text) in a table, but when I am retrieving my data back all the line breaks are missing. I am getting text put together as whole with no line breaks and with no paragraph formations.

I have tried inserting `char(10)` and `char(13)` in my text but it is not solving my problem.

I am using SQL Server 2008 as back end and c# as front end.

I am stuck on this from many days.. please reply if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a another way of doing it.  When ever you are getting text value. read it and if there is a new line then add '{newLine}' as string. and save it to sql server.
when you retrieve data you this code

```
text.Replace("{newLine}", System.Environment.NewLine);
```

you will achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")` or

```
Cell1_Table2.Text = Abc_Text.Rows[a]["xyz"].ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The line breaks would be inserted into SQL Server. However when you perform a SELECT you cannot see them as they are CHAR(10) (LF) and CHAR(13) (CR). You can try to get the values as text (instead of grid) when you query from SQL Server Management Studio. They should be visible in the text output.  Or try selecting as such:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE (column_name LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%' OR column_name LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%')
```